# Find by field in jpa play framework

Tags: java, jpa, model, playframework, persistent

I am using **JPA** in **Play 2.2.1** .How can i find by field (other than id) in my model.

I have a model User

```
@Entity
public class User{

@Id
public  Long id;

@Constraint.Required
@Email
public  String email;

@Constraint.Required
 public String password

}
```

And i want to verify that new user will not have the same email

but find function is only for primary key so **how can i findByField(String email)** in my model.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.
 1) NamedQuery
 2) Java Persistence Query Language
 3) Criteria 
 4) Native queries
       ....

Answer (score 0):

Well  unique constraint will solve your problem 
here is the code

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"email"})})
public class User{

@Id
public  Long id;

@Column(name = "email")
@Constraint.Required
@Email
public  String email;

@Constraint.Required
 public String password

}
```